# Do I need to create both Development and Production SSL Certificate Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ssl-certificate, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have Xamarin iOS app using FCM push notifications. Apple Certificates for Notifications has been expired showing `Configurable`.

When I am creating certificates, it is showing two options

- Development SSL Certificate
- Production SSL Certificate

For which option do I need to create certificates?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Yes you need to have different certificates for development production, just like different provisioning profiles.

Comment: @G.hakim - Thank you for your input.

Comment: Is that a  satisfactory answer to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to have different certificates for development and production, just like different provisioning profiles for development and production.

Comment: As a caveat, it actually depends *on* the profile that you are using.

Comment: @valdetero  Yes i totally agree with you